# ¿Como imprimir el dibujo del inkCanvas?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Hola:  Como podría hacer para imprimir el dibujo del `InkCanvas` . Según esto:

En función de cómo funciona el `InkCanvas`, no podrá imprimir los dibujos utilizando el `PrintHelper` del kit de herramientas directamente.

Para obtener los dibujos de la `InkCanvas`, puede utilizar el `InkPresenter` propiedad, que se encarga de los dibujos. A partir de ahí, puede utilizar el `StrokeContainer`, que le permite guardar los trazos del dibujo con el `SaveAsync` método. Con un `InkPersistenceFormat` de `GifWithEmbeddedIsf`, obtendrá el dibujo en formato GIF dentro de un `IOutputStream`.

Una vez que tenga el GIF en una secuencia, puede agregarlo a la vista con un control `Image`, que luego puede Agregar a los elementos de impresión e imprimirlo.

> Based on how the InkCanvas works, you won't be able to print the drawings using the toolkit's PrintHelper directly.
>   To get the drawings from the InkCanvas, you can use the InkPresenter property, which handles the drawings themselves. From there, you can use the StrokeContainer, which allows you to save the strokes of the drawing with the SaveAsync method. Using an InkPersistenceFormat of GifWithEmbeddedIsf, you'll get the drawing in GIF format inside an IOutputStream.
>   Once you have the GIF in a stream, you can add it to the view with an Image control, which you can then add to the printing elements and print it.

Comment: Falta muchisima información en tu pregunta. No nos dices que has intentado, ni que problemas te has encontrado. El texto que pones parece una traduccion de google de algun foro, si es así probablemente es mejor que añadas el enlace ya que no se entiende muy bien lo que dice.

Comment: estoy intentando imprimir el dibujo del InkCanvas en la impresora , el problema que tengo  es que no se puede imprimir utilizando el PrintHelper para imprimir el dibujo que hace el InkCanvas. Al utlizar PrintHelper me salía el asistente pero sin mostrar lo que estaba hecho en el InkCanvas.

Comment: el tema impresión ya esta resulto.